# MPFR: How to make an exact copy of mpfr_t?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, copy, mpfr

I am just stuck with how to make an exact copy of `mpfr_t` with [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org) 3.1.4: Same precision, exact same value, no rounding.

```c
void copy (mpfr_t x)
{
    mpfr_t y;
    mpfr_init2 (y, mpfr_get_prec (x));
    // Bummer: mpfr_set will round.
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(x));`? Prepend `std::` if you're using C++, if not please remove the tag.

Comment: That won't work because in C++ speek it's not trivially copyable. I am using both C and C++, a solution should work for both.

Comment: Is it supposed to compile in both C and C++?

Comment: It's actually an MPFR question because I don't want to make any assumptions about the internal workings and how rounding and heap are managed. Whatever MPFR functions you come up with, they'll do both for C and C++.

Comment: FYI, the project is in C++11. It's fine for me if the solutions for C resp. C++ are different.

Comment: I'm more familiar with `gmp` [`mpfr` is the float version with improved rounding]. But, it's similar. The typedef is like [not _exactly_]: `typedef struct mpfr mpfr_t[1];` so an implied pass-by-reference/pointer semantic. It's like `struct mpfr { mpfr_atom_t *mpfr_base; size_t mpfr_count; ... };` and we [probably] have `typedef unsigned int mpfr_atom_t;`. So, you _can't_ just use `memcpy`. Use a primitive that takes two args: (e.g.) `mpfr_init_mpfr(y,x)` that will do a `malloc` for the target number and do: `memcpy(y.mpfr_base,x.mpfr_base,..);` internally.

Comment: Since x and y have the same precision, no rounding will actually happen; so just use `mpfr_set` and use any rounding mode as the argument. Are you observing something different?

Comment: `mpfr_get_str()` + `mpfr_init_set_str()`?

Comment: If you are using C++, consider one of the C++ wrappers: https://www.mpfr.org/#interfaces

Comment: Does MPFR++ support such cloning? The project page says MPFR++ is obsolete. I already have my classes, and my code is not worse than that of a beginner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `mpfr_set` after setting the precision as you did. There will be no rounding, or if you prefer, the rounding operation will not modify the value. If the value is NaN, its sign bit will not be copied, but you probably don't care (and if you really care, you can still copy the sign bit with `mpfr_copysign`).

Do not copy the `mpfr_t` with `memcpy` or something similar. You'll get the same value after this copy, but the significand will be shared by both numbers (since one field is a pointer to the significand), and modifying one of these numbers will modify the other one, and you'll get an even more erratic behavior (possible crash...) in case the number changes to a special value (NaN, ±Inf, ±0) or its precision is changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Perhaps such a feature like `mpfr_copy` or `mpfr_clone` could be added to MPFR? At least it would be great if the documentation would explain how to get such a clone. IMO it's quite a basic feature and should be easy to implement. And it would operate faster than when a user like me does a clone by hand. You guys know when a simple memcpy is enough and when not.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts There could be a risk of misuse, depending on how such a function is defined, as it would be unlike other functions. And it would not be faster: with `mpfr_set`, if the precisions of the source and the destination are the same, MPFR detects this and copies the significand (the case where the destination is more precise than the source is also detected).

Comment: I think misuse is caused by improper documentation, not by the mere presence of a feature. Documentations of `mpfr_set` and `mpfr_clone` would have to make clear what the differences are. As I understand, you need at least 3 function calls to accomplish a clone, and you must use undocumented features. A situation that could be improved.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts A proper documentation has never prevented bugs. One needs a well-designed and consistent programming interface. And unless I've misunderstood what you want, you do not need undocumented features to implement some kind of `mpfr_clone`. Note: in case we would consider it, it is unclear whether one should do a `mpfr_init2` (i.e. assuming that the destination has not been initialized yet) or `mpfr_set_prec` (i.e. with a destination that has already been initialized, but possibly with a different precision).

Comment: The documentation states that before using a variable, it has to be be initialized by one of the initialization functions. Thus from a function named `mpfr_clone` one would expect that the target variable has been initialized. Otherwise, one would expect a function name like `mpfr_init_clone`. The result must be independent of the default precision. The precision of the result must be the same as the precision of the source, of course. That's the whole point of cloning.

Comment: ... the undocumented feature I am currently using is that the rounding performed by `mpfr_set` is a no-op if the precisions of source and destination are the same.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts This is documented in Section "Rounding Modes": "The value stored in the destination variable is correctly rounded, i.e., MPFR behaves as if it computed the result with an infinite precision, then rounded it to the precision of this variable." This implies that values that representable exactly are not affected by rounding (a well-known property).